# How to click row table and alert specific cell value

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have this script bellow, what I'm looking for is to click on any row and alert the "DT_rowID" cell value.  For the moment the error message is : Uncaught ReferenceError: table is not defined

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("body").append('<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example"><tbody></tbody></table>');
    var string_id = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/get_data_datatable.php?q=";

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/search.php?q=exosome',

        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'get',
        async: true,
        success: function(data) {


            jQuery.each(data.ids, function(i, val) {
                string_id = string_id + val + ",";
            });

            var table = $('#example').dataTable({

                "ajax": string_id,
                "columns": [{
                    "title": "Product name",
                    "data": "product_name"
                }, {
                    "title": "Quantity",
                    "data": "product_quantity"
                }, {
                    "title": "Price",
                    "data": "price_sell"
                }, {
                    "title": "Currency",
                    "data": "currency_sell"
                }, {
                    "title": "Category",
                    "data": "category"
                }, {
                    "title": "Supplier",
                    "data": "supplier_id"
                }, {
                    "title": "DT_rowID",
                    "data": "product_version_id",
                    "bVisible": false
                }]
            });

        }
    });


    $("#example").css('cursor', 'hand');
    $('#example').on('click', 'tr', function() {
        alert(table.cell(this).data());
    });

});
```

Comment: For goodness sake, format your code. You want our help, why should we have to look at a structural mess? Also, it looks like you are missing the `$.ajax()` line underneath document.ready...?  Can you create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of what is being returned?

Comment: You're defining `table` inside of your anonymous Success callback function, and then using it outside of the function, so it isn't defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work as long as that column remains the last one in the table:

```
// Added 'tbody' to prevent alert from firing when header row is clicked
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    // $(this) is the <tr> element the user clicked
    // td:last finds the last cell within that <tr>
    alert($(this).find('td:last').text());
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/th708qf9/1/